# How to create ionic video chat application

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, videochat, cometchat

I am new to ionic and i am developing an android application using ionic 2 and Laravel. I want to integrate text, audio and video chat into this app. One solution that I found is using Cometchat. It would be really helpful if you could give some pointers about what are the services available there and how to implement this video chat feature using these services. Thank you.

Comment: I've used CometChat for an Ionic app and it works perfectly.

Comment: @AlecSmart Thank you for the comment. My client is little bit worried about their pricing.

Comment: they have a cloud pricing I think as well: https://cloud.cometchat.com/pricing. You can check that out.

Comment: Which plugin did you use and how did you go about integrating it? Cometchat have taken over a week to try and tell me how to use it in a TS environment, still no answers!!!

Answer (score 0):

nowadays the Ionic 4 Can Do Your Application And This Project With [WEBRTC](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-webrtc-plugin-for-android-ios/137745) and make Your Chat Text message with socket.io technology,

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).